# how to conditionally show text in an amp-lightbox

Tags: amp-html

I'd like to show the message only if there's a sanctionSeverityClass. Is this possible in AMP? For example, in the following code block, how would I only show the

if there is a non-null sanctionSeverityClass?

```
  <amp-lightbox id="rating-lightbox" layout="nodisplay" scrollable>
    <div class='lightbox' on="tap:rating-lightbox.close" role="button" tabindex="0">
      here is some info before - would like to add conditional for next part
      <p [class]="'text-color-' + sanctionSeverityClass"><span [text]=sanctionSeverityMessage></span></p>
      here is some info after
    </div>
  </amp-lightbox>
```